# Conceptual Interpolation algorithm

Tags: c, algorithm, math, interpolation

G' Morning SO-

I'm trying to move some bounding boxes on a video. I'm at sort of a sticking point . If I've got a frame on a data file every 15 frames, then I have to create 14 frames in between each real one. Since it's a tool (actually part of an ffmpeg plugin), it needs to work for any gap size.

I've written a function that takes the distance between two points, and how many frames it has to smoothly transition from the beginning point to ending point. What this function would ideally return is an array of how many pixels to shift from the preceding frame

For example if x at frame 1 was 50, and at frame 16 was 65, then I would have an array of all ones so that each frame would add one to the frame before. Here's what I've got so far:

```
int* generateSequence(int difference, int numStep){
  int* sequence = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int*)*numStep);
  int i;
  for(i=0; i<numStep; i++){ 
    sequence[i] = 0;
  }
  while(difference > numStep){
    for(i=0; i<numStep; i++){ 
      sequence[i]++;
    }
    difference -= numStep;
  }
```

I'm satisfied with this part, (which would add one to EACH frame in between for every multiple of the distance between the two over the number of frames in between).

But now I'm getting to the point where I would need to add one to SOME frames but not all. All I've got is these jury rigged algorithms that aren't very portable for a tool that produces different frame distances...

```
double delta = difference/numStep;
if(delta >=.05 && delta< .20){
  for(i=0; i<numStep; i+=6){ 
    sequence[i]++;
  }
}
```

Should I be using a modulus operator or maybe approaching it differently? Hard coding in what seem like arbitrary values doesn't sit too well with me.

Comment: Your question here is not very clear. When you say "bounding boxes", you mean you're trying to draw a rectangle onto each frame of your video, such that the rectangle moves smoothly from its starting location to your ending location?

Comment: Yes. I have a facial recognition program that outputs coordinates and box attributes for such boxes every 15 frames, and output to a log file. I am trying to create a program to interpolate this so that the new log file will have the coordinates and attributes every frame. I know I probably didn't explain it well, and I apologize for that I'm a poor communicator. If theres anything else I can clarify let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More generally, it sounds like you want to generate the "smoothest" series of `x` integers whose sum is `y`.  (Smoothness is minimal average distance between elements in the series.)

This can be achieved with the following algorithm.

```
given sum and steps
float step = sum/steps
float delta = 0
sequence = []
for x:
    int integerstep = round(step + delta)
    delta += step - integerstep
    sequence.push(round(integerstep))
```

An example implementation in python (sorry, not a c person) can be found below.

```
def renderSmoothIntegerSequence(steps, distance):
    step = float(distance)/steps
    delta = 0
    sequence = []
    for _ in xrange(steps):
        integerstep = int(round(step + delta))
        delta += step - integerstep
        sequence.append(integerstep)
    return sequence
```

Example invocations:

```
>>> print renderSmoothIntegerSequence(5,8)
[2, 1, 2, 1, 2]
>>> print renderSmoothIntegerSequence(5,7)
[1, 2, 1, 2, 1]
>>> print renderSmoothIntegerSequence(32,1)
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>>> print renderSmoothIntegerSequence(1,50)
[50]
```

Comment: Smoothness is what I'm going for here, good word. I'm not too familiar with python, so 'integerstep', 'step', and 'delta' are all floating points in the renderSmoothIntegerSequence function correct?

Comment: @SetSlapShot I tried to write pseudocode so it's understandable.  Step and delta are floats, but integerstep represents the value that is actually added to the list, so it's an integer.

Comment: yeah something with 'integer' in its name being an integer makes a lot more sense now that I think of it :P. Well that will do it, thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

In order for this box animation to be smooth, you will need to be able to draw the rectangle on each frame such that the rectangle's coordinates are not quantized by integer. In order words, if your interpolation calculation results in (for example) an X value of 21.354 and a Y value of 50.813, then rounding these values to 21 and 51 respectively will not work; the resulting movement of the rectangle will be very jerky and irregular.

The problem is that frames of a video are pixel-based, which means there's usually no built-in way to draw lines or rectangles with real (aka floating-point, as opposed to integer) coordinates. If the library you're using to draw the rectangle onto each frame only supports integer coordinates and not floating-point coordinates (and you should check this, because many graphics libraries *do* support floating-point coordinates, which would make this task very easy for you), then you'll have to roll your own for this.

What library are you using to actually draw these rectangles onto each frame of the video?

Comment: I didn't know that was possible. I'm using libav* in the ffmpeg, I'm looking to see if there's anything about drawing floating point numbers. I really hope so that would make this so much simpler.

Comment: It doesn't work as is like that, I tried modifying the sample tracking log they provided for me with some decimals but it wouldn't run. Good idea though

Comment: It's not a good idea, it's the *only* idea. Without the ability to render your box to floating-point coordinates, you cannot get smooth animation from one position to another, unless the position and size changes naturally break on integer boundaries, which is incredibly unlikely in most cases.

Comment: Would that matter? If we're moving something one pixel (eight one hundredths of an inch) in one frame (1/30th of a second), I find it very unlikely to tell believe the human eye would be able to tell the difference

Comment: Try it and see for yourself. For any animation to be smooth, you need to either 1) be able to render to floating-point coordinates, or 2) constrain your animation so that each delta is a whole number.